# Query to do deep copy of the Objects from 2 collections in mongoDB having same key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do a deep copy of the object's data from 2 collections through the Mongo DB query.

## Example:

**Table1** data:

---

```
 {
    type:"fruits"
    box1:{
    apple:1,
    orange:2
    },
    box2:{
    one:1,
    two:2
    }
 }
```

**Table2** data:

---

```
  {
    type:"fruits"
    box1:{
    grapes:3,
    watermelon:4
    },
    box2:{
     three:3
    }
  }
```

Required Output

---

```
 {
    type:"fruits"
    box1:{
    apple:1,
    orange:2,
    grapes:3,
    watermelon:4
    },
    box2:{
    one:1,
    two:2
    three:3
    }
 }
```

I tried the below query using $mergeObjects which is resulting an error

```
db.Table1.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
            from: "Table2",
            localField: "type",
            foreignField: "type",
                as: "fromItems"
      }
   },
   {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$fromItems", 0 ] }, "$$ROOT" ] } }
   },
   { $project: { fromItems: 0 } }
])
```

For the above query the error resulting is as below:

````
```
     assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'",
        "code" : 168,
        "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
        } : aggregate failed
        _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
        doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
        assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
         DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
    @(shell):1:1

    Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'",
        "code" : 168,
        "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
    } : aggregate failed :
    _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
    doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
    assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
    DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
    @(shell):1:1```
````

How can I do the deep copy of Objects inside Object in Mongo DB query?.